# How to Read 2 Docx file and write into 3rd Docx file by append one by one docx

Tags: java

i want read 2 Docx files and write into 3rd docx file, by appending 2nd docx file into 3rd file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class DocXReadAndWrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
       {

         String fileName = "C:/Users/20123674/Downloads/DocumentScript/FileReadAndWrite/src/GUIDE - Docking Utility on SAMI EX.doc";
         String filename2 = "C:/Users/20123674/Downloads/DocumentScript/FileReadAndWrite/src/GUIDE - Docking Utility with SAMI Sync.doc";

         POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
         POIFSFileSystem fs1 = null;
         try 
         {
             fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
             fs1 =new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filename2));
             HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
             HWPFDocument doc1 =new HWPFDocument(fs1);

             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/newJapan5.doc"),true);
             doc.write(fos);
            //doc2.write(fos);

             doc1.write(fos);

            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

        }catch(Exception e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }


       }
}
```

Comment: whats the exact problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    File file1 = new File("D:\\text1.txt");
    File file2 = new File("D:\\text2.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
    String st;

    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(st);
    }

    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

    String st1;
    while ((st1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(st1);
    }

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("text3.txt"));
    writer.write(sb.toString());
    writer.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Please, don't just dump code. Explain what it does.

Comment: I am doing copying the data from first docx file which contains the images ,boarders ,fonts etc into third docx file then appending 2nd docx file it has contains images,border etc into same 3rd docx file